# How to select documents in couchbase filtered by a field other id?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have documents with schema in a bucket:

```
{
  "status": "done",
  "id": 1
}
```

I want to select all documents that have `status` as `done`.

Comment: And what did you try already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This was cross-posted to the Discourse forums: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-query-documents-by-a-field-other-than-id/20246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Couchbase Server 4.x or greater, you can use a N1QL query to do this. For instance:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM mydocuments d
WHERE d.status == 'done'
```

You also need to create an index on `status` (at least--creating indexes is more complex than a StackOverflow answer can provide) like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_status ON mydocuments (status);
```

For more information, check out the [N1QL documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/index.html) and the [interactive N1QL tutorial](https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/).

Comment: That query should have a single equals sign, not two.